# get combination results of 5 variables PHP

Tags: php

what i have is 5 diferent inputs that user can fill or not

- input1:
- input2:
- input3:
- input4:
- input5:

summing up each input has an state 0 or 1, not filled or filled.

what i need to do is get all 32 combinations in a easy and short way.

what i tried to do is something like this

```
i1 = trim($_POST['input1']);
i2 = trim($_POST['input2']);
i3 = trim($_POST['input3']);
i4 = trim($_POST['input4']);
i5 = trim($_POST['input5']);

if(empty(i1) and empty(i2) and empty(i3) and empty(i4) and empty(i5))
{ 
     code = '00000';
     sentence = sentencesql(code); // i have a sql for each combination
} 
elseif (empty(i1) and empty(i2) and empty(i3) and empty(i4) and !empty(i5))
{
     code = '00001';
     sentence = sentencesql(code);
}
.
.
.
// each and every combination
.
.
elseif(!empty(i1) and !empty(i2) and !empty(i3) and !empty(i4) and !empty(i5))
{
     code = '11111';
     sentence = sentencesql(code);
}
```

this works  but the code is pretty extensive

any ideas of how to shorten the code???

Comment: Variables in PHP are denoted with a `$` prefix.

Comment: yes you're right sorry about that i forgot the $

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$code = "";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $code += (trim($_POST['input'+$i]) == "") ? "0" : "1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
i1 = (empty(trim($_POST['input1']))?'0':'1');// si vide i1 = '0' sinon i1= '1' 
i2 = (empty(trim($_POST['input2']))?'0':'1');
i3 = (empty(trim($_POST['input3']))?'0':'1');
i4 = (empty(trim($_POST['input4']))?'0':'1');
i5 = (empty(trim($_POST['input5']))?'0':'1');

code = i1 . i2 . i3 . i4 . i5;// crer le code en concatenant les resultat
sentence = sentencesql(code);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you just write them as this:

```
i1 = trim($_POST['input1']);
i2 = trim($_POST['input2']);
i3 = trim($_POST['input3']);
i4 = trim($_POST['input4']);
i5 = trim($_POST['input5']);

code = i1 . i2 . i3 . i4 . i5;
sentence = sentencesql(code);
```

This will produce what you want, i might think.

Normal variables are with $, it will look like this:

```
$i1 = trim($_POST['input1']);
$i2 = trim($_POST['input2']);
$i3 = trim($_POST['input3']);
$i4 = trim($_POST['input4']);
$i5 = trim($_POST['input5']);

$code = $i1 . $i2 . $i3 . $i4 . $i5;
$sentence = sentencesql($code);
```

Comment: trim() just delete whitespace so if there are another data in inputs, $code will be filled with them

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
for($i=1;$i<=32;$i++)
{
  if(empty(trim($_POST['input'.$i])))
    $code .= '0';
  elseif(!empty(trim($_POST['input'.$i])))
    $code .= '1';
}
 $sentence = sentencesql($code);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do exactly what you want:

```
$code = "";
$code .= empty($_POST['input1']) ? 0 : 1;
$code .= empty($_POST['input2']) ? 0 : 1;
$code .= empty($_POST['input3']) ? 0 : 1;
$code .= empty($_POST['input4']) ? 0 : 1;
$code .= empty($_POST['input5']) ? 0 : 1;
$sentence = sentencesql($code);
```

Comment: doing trim() to the post this worked great!! thanks!